# How do I get the Subscriber UID in Simplenews to Create Personalized Newsletters?

Tags: views, emails

I am using the insert view module to create a personalized newsletter, now I need to pass the subscriber uid as a parameter to the view but I am not finding a way to do that. Any ideas ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible in Drupal 6.

Simplenews 7.x-1.x now provides a simplenews_subscriber variable for the body template. It also automatically switches the global user to the one that is receiving the mail while it is generated.